# How to keep the process alive?

Tags: java, process, testng, processbuilder

I am triggering an executable file through the ProcessBuilder in java and I would like to keep the process open till the entire test execution is completed in testng. The reason is other tests will send some type of commands to this executable. Below is my code to trigger the executable. Can someone tell me if it is possible to achieve this? I really don't have any idea regarding this, so any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("executableFilePath").start();
process.waitFor();
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. The executable that you starts decides on its own how long it wants to run. If it finishes, then it is finished. You cannot avoid this. Maybe you want to run this process in a separate ```Thread```. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for your word of advice. Multithreading solved the issue as mentioned. Thank you so much!!